# I made a map that violated four color map theorem, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: discrete-geometry

[image: enter image description here]]

Hi, so I made this map. I was wondering what I did wrong.

Comment: you could replace blue with red.

Comment: yeah, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

Try colouring the area that is currently blue red instead.